# Android View not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Not showing views,
the above topselection view contain two views.
The below method called that time the content not showing like textview
and image view, event text and images are assigned properly.

```
public void updateview()
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(adapterContext);
        draggableGrid.removeAllViews();
        dragArray.clear();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) adapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for(int index = 0;index<pData.picturelist.size();index++)
        {   
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.topselectionview, null);
            //buttons do not work with draggable grid view hence text view is used
            TextView i = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ImageView img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.selectionImage);

            //i = new TextView(adapterContext);  

            i.setPadding(5, pData.topPadding, 5, (int) (pData.columnheight*0.056f));

            i.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);   


            //set the text properties for the image tag
            i.setTextAppearance(adapterContext, R.style.imageTag);

            i.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.BOTTOM);

            if(cutrecordid!=null)
                if(cutrecordid.equals(pData.picturelist.get(index).cid))
                    continue;
            //get the path of the image
            String image = pData.picturelist.get(index).imagePath;
            String pp="";
            if(image.contains("custom_images")){
                pp = AvazAppActivity.avazRootDir+"/avaz/" + image;
            }else{
                if(AvazAppActivity.isValidImage(image)){
                    if(image.startsWith("ci_"))
                        pp = AvazAppActivity.avazRootDir+"/avaz/user1/custom_images/" + image;
                    else
                        pp = AvazAppActivity.avazRootDir+"/avaz/png/" + image;
                }               
            }
            bitmapImage = AvazAppActivity.loadIm.readBitmapFromSDCard(pp);

            //get the bitmap of the image
            Drawable bgrImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);

            if(bitmapImage != null)
            {
                int drawablepadding=0;
                int ch=(pData.columnwidth*(pData.imgPercent))/100;
                int cw=(pData.columnwidth*(pData.imgPercent))/100;
                try{
                    int h1=(cw*bgrImage.getIntrinsicHeight())/bgrImage.getIntrinsicWidth();
                    int w1=(ch*bgrImage.getIntrinsicWidth())/bgrImage.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    if(h1>ch)
                        h1=ch;
                    else if(w1>cw)
                        w1=cw;
                    int pad=0;
                    if(ch>h1){
                        pad=(ch-h1)/2;
                    }
                    drawablepadding=pad;
                    bgrImage.setBounds( 0, pad, w1, pad+h1 );
                }catch(ArithmeticException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                i.setCompoundDrawables(null, bgrImage, null, null);

                i.setCompoundDrawablePadding(drawablepadding);
                try {
                    OverlayScreen.class.getDeclaredMethod("setPictureFontStyle",new Class[]{View.class,Integer.class}).invoke(adapterContext, i,pData.txtSize);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                try {
                    OverlayScreen.class.getDeclaredMethod("setPictureFontStyle",new Class[]{View.class,Integer.class}).invoke(adapterContext, i,(int)(pData.txtSize + pData.txtSize*0.5));
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            i.setText(getTruncateText(pData.picturelist.get(index).templateName,i));
            //set the tag of the text view to identify the view when clicked
            i.setTag(pData.picturelist.get(index));

            i.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER);

            if(pData.picturelist.get(index).enabled == true)
            {
                //draw the category of template in the enabled state
                if(pData.picturelist.get(index).type.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
                    i.setBackgroundDrawable(adapterContext.getResources().getDrawable(ColorManager.getCatBGIdWithoutEffect(pData.picturelist.get(index).color,prefs.getString("colorcode", "solid"))));
                else
                    i.setBackgroundDrawable(adapterContext.getResources().getDrawable(ColorManager.getTempBGIdWithoutEffect(pData.picturelist.get(index).color,prefs.getString("colorcode", "solid"))));
            }
            else
            {
                //draw the category of template in the disabled state
                if(pData.picturelist.get(index).type.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
                    i.setBackgroundDrawable(adapterContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.disablefolder));
                else
                    i.setBackgroundDrawable(adapterContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.disabletemplate));
            }      

            i.setHeight(i.getBackground().getBounds().height());
            i.setWidth(i.getBackground().getBounds().width());   

            //add the text view to the grid and to array 
            draggableGrid.addView(view);
            dragArray.add(view);      

        } 
    }
```

The below is xml file where having elements.

```
topselectionview.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selectionImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/correct_highlighted"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi even i used that also giving blank. there is no log cat error

Comment: e.printStackTrace() goes to the Console, not LogCat. If you want to see errors in LogCat, change your statements to something like Log.e(e.getMessage()).

Answer (score 0):

***This is not the answer to question but i just want you know***

- ***Just a note*** :: `setBackgroundDrawable` -> `View.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)`
- This method was deprecated in `API level 16`. use
  `setBackground(Drawable)` instead

**Source**:[***Developer Docs***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))